# How to run ios 6 (iPhone 5)app in all old iphone devices?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6

I have developed an iPhone App in IOS 6.0 simulator  which is running fine for iPhone 5(Retina 4).
but it is not running comfortable for old iPhone devices.
i want some solutions that what i have to do?
do i have to write some code for this that for each device it should run comfortable.
FINAL conclusion is that i want my iPhone APP which is developed in ios 6.0 for iPhone 5 must also run on all old iPhone devices...
Please give some link or any tutorial or any example so that it will easy for me to do this.

Comment: Are you having performance problems or compatibility problems?

Comment: thanks nneonneo for answering . i dont have performance problems.actually my client wants an iPhone app and i am making it in ios 6.0 so when i am sending him ipa to test iPhone app but he is iPhone 4 so the app is not running in his device..the main problem is this only ..so i want app to be made in ios 6.0 that should compatiable with all iPhone devices

Comment: You have used any framwwork in tour app?

Comment: not working means not starting or display is not proper?

Comment: it won't be helpful for you, but... why don't you leave the developer job for the professionals instead? :)

Comment: hey frnd durgaprasad actually it is working fine in iphone5 as it is made for iphone 5 ..but i want to working fine in old iphone devices too but it is not working for me ...

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to decide if you actually care about those older devices. The market share for iOS 4.x devices and lower is probably less than 5% at this point ([source](http://david-smith.org/iosversionstats/), though he tracks only iOS 4.x and up).

If it's a performance issue on older devices, then you may have to turn off fancier features for them (e.g. turn down the complexity of a 3D app, use fewer animations and cache less often, use lower-resolution assets, etc.). If it's a compatibility issue with earlier OS versions, you will have to target a lower iOS version in your development.

If you must use features from iOS 5 and later, then you would probably be better off just dropping support for older devices (this is the path Apple encourages for the most part, especially for new apps). It will also reduce your development costs to focus only on newer platforms, though you do have to be mindful of the tradeoff.

Comment: thanks nneonneo for answering . i dont have performance problems.actually my client wants an iPhone app and i am making it in ios 6.0  for new iPhone 5 resolutions,so when i am sending him ipa to test iPhone app but he is iPhone 4 so the app is not running in his device..the main problem is this only ..so i want app to be made in ios 6.0 that should compatiable with all iPhone devices.so that my iPhone app should compatiabale with all old iPhone devices screen resolutions too..